# how can i detect if spacebar is pressed in tkinter without using other modules

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")


def func(event):
    if event.char=="a":
        print("a is pressed")

root.bind("<KeyPress>",func)
root.mainloop()
```

here when a key is presssed it checks if it is "a" or not and prints "a is pressed"
just like that is there anyway to know if the key pressed is "space" or not with tkinter only

Comment: Doesn't `event.char == ' '` work?

Comment: yep it works i was using ```event.char='space'``` and wondering why its not working Thnaks

Comment: if that works I'll put it as an answer for future readers then.

Comment: funny thing, you could first use `print( event.char )` and you would see that you need `" "` instead of `"space"`

Comment: @furas  i printed it printed   but i thought it printed nothing

Comment: guys, any idea how can i use keys like "shift","CapsLock" with ```window.bind("KeyPress")``` and ```window.bind("<KeyRelease>")```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way to do this.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")


def func(event):
    if event.char=="a":
        print("a is pressed")
    elif event.char==" ":
        print("Space is pressed")
        

root.bind("<KeyPress>",func)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to bind  to another function. use this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")


def func(event):
    if event.char=="a":
        print("a is pressed")
def func2():
    print("space is pressed")

root.bind("<KeyPress>",func)
root.bind("<space>",func2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: well you can do that but i need two functions to work when key is pressed and when it is released like ```root.bind("KeyRelease",func2)``` so just binding space doesnt work

Comment: you can use one function in that 2 bind:     root.bind("<KeyPress>",func)   and    root.bind("<space>",func). then event.char will be ' '

Answer (score 1):

The character for space is  . The following should work.

```py
def func(event):
    if event.char == ' ':
        print("Space is pressed")
```